# SSH Tunnel via crontab with 2FA gives EOFError

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, tunnel, stdin

I'm trying to setup a crontab which opens an ssh tunnel. Unlike other questions here and on stackoverflow, the server I'm connecting to has a 2FA which prompts the user for a password. However, I don't want to enter anything because the tunnel is already setup at that point, instead I would like the process to just idle so that I can run other commands using a separate process. Running the command

```
ssh <server> -L <tunnelingport>:<remote_host>:<targetport>
```

works ok in a terminal, I leave the process at the prompt for the 2FA password. But, when I run via crontab I get an EOFError:

```
Enter your 2FA password: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/shellwrap/shellwrap.py", line 74, in <module>
    response = str(raw_input('Enter your 2FA password: '))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

My very limited understanding is that I need to manage stdin somehow. I'm sure there is some combination of the -n -f -t -T flags that can allow me to maintain the tunnel without throwing an exception, but I'm completely stumped.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the ssh ["-N" flag](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#N). This prevents ssh from invoking a command on the remote system:

> **-N**
> Do not execute a remote command. This is useful for just forwarding ports. Refer to the description of SessionType in ssh_config(5) for details.

If you want to put the option into the ssh config file, you would use the option "SessionType none" as described [here](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#SessionType):

> **SessionType**
> May be used to either request invocation of a subsystem on the remote system, or to prevent the execution of a remote command at all. The latter is useful for just forwarding ports. The argument to this keyword must be **none** (same as the **-N** option), **subsystem** (same as the **-s** option) or **default** (shell or command execution).

You may also want to use the [**-f**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#f) option to have ssh go into the background after authentication, or the equivalent configuration option [**ForkAfterAuthentication**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ForkAfterAuthentication)

.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!